# CORS Logging into an expressjs/passportjs app 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ajax, node.js, cordova, express, cors

I am converting a web app into a cordova app the only thing stopping me is the fact that the app is expressjs based, since cordova requires an index.html I need to use CORS to render the app and provide the login session.

I can use ajax/CORS with regular pages but when it comes to authorization I am stuck.

I use passportjs to authenticate on this POST route `app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login'));` so on my client side cordova app I make an ajax call to make this request for me.

```
$('body').on('submit', '#logIn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://mysite.io:3300/login",
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function(response){
            alert('succeeded!');
            console.log(response);
            alert(response);
        },
        failure: function(message){
            alert("failed");
            console.log(message);
            alert(message);
        }
    });

});
```

When I make the POST request I get a `401 Unauthorized` so I have been doing research on that, I still am not sure why it's not authorizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Passport docs](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/):

> By default, if authentication fails, Passport will respond with a 401 Unauthorized status, and any additional route handlers will not be invoked.

The username/password combination you're posting is not valid.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks again Ill focus on making sure the user/pass is being sent correctly.

Comment: Nice that fixed it... wow wish I payed more attention to that I had `JSON.stringify(formData)` changed it to `formData` silly mistake.. Now the POST just sits there, do I need to make another ajax request on success or on the server send data?

Comment: A successful authentication via AJAX will not refresh the page.  If you want something to change, you'll have to change it yourself.

Comment: Yeah I got that sorted out sorry it was just a matter of wrapping my head around it. Thanks

Comment: No problem.  One more thing you've learned in your magical programming journey!